# Term independent of $x$ in $(\frac{1}{60} - \frac{x^8}{81})(2x^2 - \frac {3}{x^2})^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A question came up and was deleted while I was trying to figure it out, but the main question was as in this title,

> what is the term independent of $x$ in $(\frac{1}{60} - \frac{x^8}{81})(2x^2 - \frac {3}{x^2})^6$?

The answer given and listed by another user surprised me and the question disappeared before I could resolve the issue for myself.  That answer was $-36$ and is supposed to account for the whole of the term independent of $x$.  But both the question asker and the commenting user only discussed the $x^{-8}$ term from the second bracket interacting with the paired term from the first bracket.

My question:  is there not also a contribution to the constant term from $\frac 1{60}(2\cdot2x^2\cdot\frac {-3}{x^2})^3$?

Comment: Hi, I was the user who commented on the previous post that you mention. I only referred to that part to resolve the user's query of getting $6$ for that part.

Comment: The complete answer is $$\binom65\times2\times(-3)^5\times\left(-\frac{1}{81}\right) + \binom63\times\frac{1}{60}\times2^3\times(-3)^3$$$$=36 + (-72) = -36$$ and I clarified the first bit for the previous OP.

Comment: @insipidintegrator got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[x^n]$ denotes the coefficient of $x^n.$ Then

$$[x^0](\frac{1}{60} - \frac{x^8}{81})(2x^2 - \frac {3}{x^2})^6=[x^{12}](\frac{1}{60} - \frac{x^8}{81})(2x^4 -  {3})^6=[x^{12}]\frac{1}{60} (2x^4 -  {3})^6-[x^{12}]\frac{x^8}{81}(2x^4 -  {3})^6=[x^{12}]\frac{1}{60} (2x^4 -  {3})^6-[x^{4}]\frac{1}{81}(2x^4 -  {3})^6=[x^{3}]\frac{1}{60} (2x -  {3})^6-[x^1]\frac{1}{81}(2x -  {3})^6=\frac{1}{60} 2^3 \cdot (-3)^3 \cdot  \binom{6}{3}-\frac{1}{81} 2 \cdot (-3)^5 \cdot 6=-36
$$

Comment: Replacing $[x^n]$ by $a_n$ would make for a much easier read, in my opinion.

Comment: Easy to read but hard to calculate. The notation $[x^n]$  is widely accepted in combinatorics.

Comment: Ah, I just asked because I never saw that before. Must have been because my combinatorics education was only limited to high-school level.